# Отправка byte[] на wearable устройство Android

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Пытаюсь отправить массив байт с мобильно на часы. С отправкой примитивных  типов все ок, но отправить массив байт не получается:
Запрос со смартфона отправляю так:

```
  public void sendDataToWearable(final byte[] bytes) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "sendDataToWearable(final byte[] bytes) invoke");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PutDataMapRequest dataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(WearableService.PATH_STATE_DATA);
                dataMapRequest.getDataMap().putByteArray(WearableService.TAG_DATAMAP_DATA, bytes);
                dataMapRequest.getDataMap().toByteArray();
                dataMapRequest.setUrgent();
                Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, dataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest())
                        .await();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

на часах обрабатываю так:

```
private void parseByteArray(DataEvent event) {
    ArrayList<UObject> objects = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;

    bytes = DataMap.fromByteArray(event.getDataItem().getData()).getByteArray(TAG_DATAMAP_DATA);
    try {
        objects = (ArrayList<UObject>) SerializationHelper.readToByteArray(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что на часах метод  `onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents)` не отрабатывает, такое ощущение что я запрос на смартфоне неправильно формирую.